# avoiding exponential notation in JSON_EXTRACT function in BigQuery

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery and store JSON string in some fields.
here, I have a field named "json" that contains JSON string like this:

```
{"log_id":939286972300751993,"status":"good"}
```

and querying with sql below:

```
SELECT json, JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.log_id") AS log_id
FROM dataset.table;
```

the result is:

```
                    json                         |       log_id
-------------------------------------------------+---------------------
{"log_id": 939286972300751993, "status": "good"} | 9.39286972300752e+17
```

but what I expect is:

```
                    json                         |       log_id
-------------------------------------------------+---------------------
{"log_id": 939286972300751993, "status": "good"} | 939286972300751993
```

"log_id" should be treated as INTEGER in my context.
Is there any way to avoid JSON_EXTRACT function replace large integer to exponential notation?

Comment: As far as I know, the JSON spec doesn't impose any limit on number ranges but most libraries do have limits. You'll probably be on the safe side if you switch to strings: `{"log_id":"939286972300751993","status":"good"}`

Comment: Thanks for replay. Yes, I think you are right. I would do as you said if I can redefine schema, but I already have huge dataset containing data as I explained and it is hard to update all of them.

Comment: How do you throw your query? via the GUI, via the API?

Comment: I tryied both web GUI and API and the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast the result to INTEGER in the query itself.

```
SELECT json, INTEGER(JSON_EXTRACT(json, "$.log_id")) AS log_id
FROM dataset.table;
```

As noted in the comments to your question, storing large numbers in JSON may cause you to lose precision for any numbers over 2^53 (search for "numeric" in http://rfc7159.net/rfc7159). If that happens, precision would be lost in the JSON parsing library itself, so casting to an INTEGER elsewhere in the query (or making some API-level change) would not help.

Comment: I understand the point. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jeremy-condit & @Álvaro-gonzález about storing large numbers, however sometimes you don't have the ability to change the data you are given..

As the answer of casting the `JSON_EXTRACT` result to an integer results in null values, I have resorted to using a `regexp_extract`.

Although not the best approach, this may be useful to others:

```
SELECT json, integer(regexp_extract(json, "\"log_id\":([0-9]*),")) as log_id
FROM dataset.table;
```